# Vertical mobile page and high resolution

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive, resolution

I create Responsive pages with Bootstrap, and use CSS'es:

```
@media (max-width:991px;) {} etc.
```

I opened page on mobile phone in vertical position and what I haven't expected
it has resolution bigger than 768px, so my formatting for lower mobile resolutions doesn't apply and it's unreadable, on the other hand if I change that, it will be to big on other devices like tablets.

How do you recommend to manage that?

Comment: This question is too broad. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use more breakpoints in the media queries to better manage the displaying on different devices:

```
/* Mobile First Method */

    // add stuff here for mobile

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    // add stuff here for tablet

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1366px) {

    // add stuff here for desktop

}

// you can modify the device pixel ratio according to your needs
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
       only screen and ( min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
       only screen and ( -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
       only screen and ( min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
       only screen and ( min-resolution: 192dpi),
       only screen and ( min-resolution: 2dppx) {

    // add stuff here for retina devices

    /* you can use the breakpoints used above:
     * @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
     * 
     *  // add stuff here for retina tablet
     * 
     * }
     * 
     * @media only screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
     * 
     *  // add stuff here for retina desktop
     * 
     * }
     */

}

@media print {

    // add stuff here for print

}
```

Comment: Thank you, 
I found out problem was viewport declaration missing

Comment: Thank you I was able to CSS myt table to fit vertical mobile screen by max-width on media CSS. Now if mobile and max-wdith 480px myt table prints beatufully to vertical resolution on mobile device.